# YARN: What is the difference between number-of-executors and executor-cores in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I am learning Spark on AWS EMR. In the process I am trying to understand the difference between number of executors(--num-executors) and executor cores (--executor-cores). Can any one please tell me here?

Also when I am trying to submit the following job, I am getting error:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --num-executors 1 --executor-cores 5   --executor-memory 1g -–conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false wordcount.py s3://test/spark-example/input/input.txt s3://test/spark-example/output21

Error: Unrecognized option: -–conf
```

Answer (score 15):

**Number of executors** is the number of distinct yarn containers  (think processes/JVMs) that will execute your application.

**Number of executor-cores** is the number of threads you get inside each executor (container).

So the parallelism (number of concurrent threads/tasks running) of your spark application is `#executors X #executor-cores`. If you have 10 executors and 5 executor-cores you will have (hopefully) 50 tasks running at the same time.

Comment: what's the difference between executor-cores and spark.executor.cores?

Comment: @rileyss they are synonyms. The one is used in the configuration settings whereas the other was used when adding the parameter as a command line argument. I just used one of the two on the example here, but there was no particular reason why I choose one over the other.